# CakePHP Login element

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

Maybe a simple question but how do I change my login box after logging in. Such as 'Welcome user' 
I can't find good examples ...

My code looks like this
users_controller
function login {
}.. with login element

Comment: post your code so we can take a look!

Answer (score 2):

See here as example: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/56ff0ce37fb06a30

You have 2 options:

1. Depending of your login state, choose another element, like:

   ```
   function login() {
       if ($isUserLoggedIn == false) {
          // render login element
       } else {
          // render welcome element
       }
   }
   ```
2. **this is more bad option** In login element add logic like:

   ```
   if (!$isUserLoggedIn) {
      // echo html and code for login
   } else {
      // echo html and code for welcome
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want an action/view that can be rendered by both logged and not logged in users.

Similar to riky's the following code might help you

In your controller:

```
//check if user is logged in and set $user_details variable in the view
if($this->Auth->User()){ 
 $user_details = $this->Auth->User();
}
$this->set(compact('user_details'));
```

In your view:

```
<? //check if $user_details variable is set (user is logged in) and display the correct element
if(isset($user_details){
 echo $this->element('welcome_box',array('user_details'=>$user_details));
}else{
 echo $this->element('login_box');
}
?>
```